# Sending messages to released objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have several UIView subclasses (buttons, labels, etc.) that follow the following setup pattern. My question is, why are messages still able to be sent to the `UILabel` after `release`?

```
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
    [someUIView addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];

     myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

     // other property changes to myLabel
```

They are "owned" by a new UIView, I suppose, but I don't understand why `release` doesn't destroy the original object and thereby all messages to it. I'm not making property changes through `someUIView`'s `subViews`. I'm not complaining. I'm just trying to understand why.

***EDIT:** I should add that these are instance variables, if that makes a difference.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still send messages to the label because the label hasn't been released yet. `-addSubview:` retains the objects passed in, so the object remains in memory since the view is still holding a reference and you didn't nil the `myLabel` pointer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! How would I know when another method is going to call release implicitly? Is there some list that I should be aware of? (Other than looking at the NSObject retainCount)

Comment: After releasing an object do not use it.

Comment: The short answer is... don't worry about it. Sure, I happen to know that `-addSubview:` performs a retain on an object, but it's not necessary. As for `retainCount`, just don't bother. Seriously. It's an implementation detail that will just lead to madness.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Could you elaborate on my response to @CocoaFu?

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Once you have released an object, you shouldn't use that reference to it again.  In this case, it works only by coincidence;  coincidence that -addSubview: happens to retain it. Assuming `myLabel` is a local variable, move the release to be after the last use.  Note that the static analyzer should complain about this code (and rightly so).

Comment: I didn't say it was right. I was just explaining why it happened to be working.

Answer (score 3):

The object is not destroyed as long as the retain count is greater than 0. In this case `someUIView` has retained the object.

It is really best not to access an object after releasing it. a better pattern might be:

```
myLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame] autorelease];
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[someUIView addSubview:myLabel];
myLabel = nil;
```

Second example:

```
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
[someUIView addSubview:myLabel];
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

// other property changes to myLabel

[myLabel release];
myLabel = nil;
```

Comment: The only reason I have property changes after the release is because other methods in the class are changing them. I wasn't sure where else to put the release if at any given time, another method could be changing its properties.

Comment: Then release after setting the `textAlignment`, see my second example.  A suggestion" Use ARC, it will take care of all the retains and releases.

Comment: If `myLabel` is an instance variables and other methods in your class might be changing `myLabel`, then every change should first release the existing value and then assign anew.  However, this sounds awfully fragile, if that is really what is happening;  how would you ensure that, say, the `textAlignment` remains consistent?

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `-addSubview:` calls `-retain` on the label when it receives it. At this point, you relinquish ownership (by calling `-release`) and only the view owns it. But it still exists until the containing view also releases it.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are probably retained before...

Comment: That's what I thought, but upon further inspection, I see no apparent prior retains.